# Can I hide the whole GUI in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt-creator

In fullscreen mode the menubar, left sidebar, and a bottom bar remains. I'm fairly good with its keyboard shortcuts and I'd like to try "distraction-free" programming. Is it possible?

Comment: I made a feature request ticket for distraction-free editing mode in Qt Creator. You can give it an up-vote if you like. https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-15867

Answer (score 3):

In the current version of QtCreator (3.5.0), there are options in the *Window* menu to hide the "mode selector" and left sidebar (which is also toggle-able via `Alt+0`). The bottom panel can be closed, but it doesn't look like the bar itself can be.

Another way to achieve this is to split the current document panel into a new window, and then fullscreen that panel. (The split screen button is in the top-right corner of the panel -> choose "Open in New Window".) The default keyboard shortcut is `Ctrl+E`, `4`, or alternatively you can use *Window* -> *Open in New Window*.

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> to show/hide side bar and press <kbd>Esc</kbd> key a number of times until bottom bar minimizes.

These shortcuts are not specific to fullscreen mode.

Answer (score 2):

**Horizontal space:**

To hide the **mode selector** and to save space on the display, select Window > Mode Selector Style > Hidden. To only show icons on the mode selector, select the Icons Only style.

How to set a shortcut:

Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard

In the keyboard shortcut filter search for "CycleModeSelectorStyle". Set a keyboard shortcut, e.g. Ctrl + Shift + M

This in combination with the shortcut mentioned by other answers: Alt + 0 will give the maximum available space horizontally.

**Vertical space:**

From menu select: Window -> Full Screen (Ctrl + Shift + F11)

The vertical space could be saved even more, but due to QtCreator OR Unity bug, this feature has been disabled https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/194300/